# Different column width in `tcolorbox` with `sidebyside` option

Tags: tcolorbox, sidebyside, column-width

The default output of `sidebyside` option in `tcolorbox` environment is two equal-side columns (Refer to the MWE). But what is needed is to produce difference two difference column width. How can we get the first column with `.7\textwidth` and the second column with `.3\textwidth`?

```
\documentclass{article}
    \usepackage{tcolorbox}
    \begin{document}
        \begin{tcolorbox}[sidebyside]
            hello world hello world hello world 
            \tcblower
            world
        \end{tcolorbox}
    \end{document}
```

Comment: You can use `righthand width=.3\textwidth`.

Comment: Pretty fine @SalimBou :) I looked for this key yesterday, I did not meet it. Actually, in was written in an illustrating example on page 67 of the manual.

Answer (score 5):

According to @SalimBou's comment, we can use the ready-made key `righthand width`.

```
\documentclass{article}
    \usepackage{tcolorbox}
    \begin{document}
        \begin{tcolorbox}[sidebyside,righthand width=.3\textwidth]
            hello world hello world hello world 
            \tcblower
            world
        \end{tcolorbox}
    \end{document}
```